# Exploding Runge Kutta Method

Tags: c++, bash, physics, projectile, runge-kutta

I've been attempting to build a Runge Kutta fourth order integrator to model simple projectile motion. My code is as follows

```
double rc4(double initState, double (*eqn)(double,double),double now,double dt)
{
        double k1 = eqn(initState,now);
        double k2 = eqn(initState + k1*dt/2.0,now + dt/2.0);
        double k3 = eqn(initState + k2*dt/2.0,now + dt/2.0);
        double k4 = eqn(initState + k3*dt, now + dt);

        return initState + (dt/6.0) * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
}
```

This is called within a while loop

```
while (time <= duration && yPos >=0)
                {

                        xPos = updatePosX(xPos,vx,timeStep);
                        yPos = updatePosY(yPos,vy,timeStep);


                        vx = rc4(vx,updateVelX,time,timeStep);
                        vy = rc4(vy,updateVelY,time,timeStep);

                        cout << "x Pos: " << xPos <<"\t y Pos: " << yPos << endl;

                        time+=timeStep;

                        myFile << xPos << "  " << yPos << "  " << vx << "  " << vy << endl;

                }
```

However, contrary to what should happen my results simply blow up. What's going on here?

Comment: Did you mean to call `rc4(updateVelX, vx, time, timeStep)` instead of `rc4(vx, updateVelX, time, timeStep) (notice the inversion of the first 2 arguments)?

Comment: Yes, I want to update using the time step

Comment: I have attempted to fix the code as shown above, and am still running into the same issue.

Comment: What do you mean by it "blows up"?  Infinite loop?  There isn't enough code present to know what's going on. Where is duration initialized?  The updatePos functions?

Comment: Duration is initialized with input. I mean the update positron functions blow up. For full code please see.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013383/implementation-of-runge-kutta-fourth-order-in-c/28013421#28013421

Comment: @user3277807 - So what does your debugger tell you?

Comment: I'm sorry in New to c++ abd have never used a debugger

Answer (score 0):

Your rk4 code looks right. But only for scalar differential equations.

What you most certainly have is a system of coupled differential equations in a dimension greater than 1. Here you have to apply the integration method in its vector form. That is, `x,y,vx,vy` are combined into a 4 dimensional (phase) state vector and the system function is vector valued, `k1,...k4` are vectors etc.

As an advanced note, `time <= duration` is sensible to rounding errors accumulated in the repetitions of `time+=timeStep;`. Better use `time <= duration-timeStep/2` to have `time` at the end of the loop close to `duration`.

---

Reading the code on the closed previous question I see that you have problems with the idea of a differential equation. You should not use the result of the Euler step as acceleration in the RK4 implementation. The system for ballistic motion without air friction is

```
dotx = vx
doty = vy
dotvx = 0
dotvy = -g
```

which you would have to implement in vector form as something like

```
eqn(t, [x,y,vx,vy]) // where X = array of double of dimension 4
   { return [vx,vy,0,-g]; }
```